# Customizing Django User model yields error

Tags: python, django, rest

I have created a custom `User` model inheriting from the Django one in `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
# Create your models here.


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

# triggered as soon as a new user is saved in the db
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Following [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), I also add my app to `INSTALLED_APP` and change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for WestMolkkyClubBackend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '******************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.12']
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.User'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'WestMolkkyClubBackend'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have also updated `admin.py`:

```
# Register your models here.
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

However I get the following errors when trying to migrate:

```
 SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
admin.LogEntry.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
admin.LogEntry.user: (fields.E307) The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.user', but app 'WestMolkkyClubBackend' doesn't provide model 'user'.
authtoken.Token.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
authtoken.Token.user: (fields.E307) The field authtoken.Token.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'WestMolkkyClubBackend.user', but app 'WestMolkkyClubBackend' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Did you try to write `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'User'`?

Comment: Is `WestMolkkyClubBackend` the last directory that contains this `User` model? Did you made any migrations before adding your custom `Use

Comment: Do your models.py live under WestMolkkyClubBackend directory??

Answer (score 0):

I reset my project while using the custom `User` model during the first migration and it works. It was probably a project structure issue.